# FontAwesome react-native warnings

Tags: react-native, font-awesome, react-native-web

i am trying to use `fontawesome` in `react-native-web-app`

Did everything as suggested in docs, but for some reason getting this warning in console.

`<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} style={[styles.icon]} />` - this is the part which triggers all warnings. If I will remove it , warning are gone too.

Warnings:

> Warning: React does not recognize the `secondaryFill` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `secondaryfill` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
>
> Warning: React does not recognize the `secondaryOpacity` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `secondaryopacity` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
>
> Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Path which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference. Learn more about using refs safely here: https://reactjs.org/link/strict-mode-find-node
>
> Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Svg which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference. Learn more about using refs safely here: https://reactjs.org/link/strict-mode-find-node

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a known issue with an open pull request in the library: https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-native-fontawesome/pull/74

For now, the [last comment in that thread offers a workaround](https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-native-fontawesome/pull/74#issuecomment-923856999). You can use [@fortawesome/react-fontawesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome) for web, and `react-native-fontawesome` for Android/iOS.

Copying their code snippet here:

```
import {FontAwesomeIcon as FontAwesomeReact} from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import {FontAwesomeIcon as FontAwesomeNative} from '@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome';
import {number} from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

FaIcon.propTypes = {
  size: number,
};
export default function FaIcon({size, style, ...props}) {
  if (Platform.OS === 'web') {
    const webStyles = StyleSheet.flatten([style, {width: size, height: size}]);
    return <FontAwesomeReact {...props} style={webStyles} />;
  }

  return <FontAwesomeNative {...props} size={size} style={style} />;
}
```